# Select Inner Join Select in SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join

Hi  i Have a Select Inner Join Statement it seems ok  but i got error. this is my query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[POBalance]  @PONumber nvarchar(50)
AS BEGIN
Select( 
Select 
    A.Description,
    C.qty as POqty,
    B.QtyDelivered as PDQty, 
    case when A.partialflag ='false' 
    then '0'
    else
    A.qty  end as Balance,
    A.Unit,
    A.Unitprice,
    A.Partialflag 
from tblPOdetails as A

Inner Join  ( SELECT  id, SUM(Qty) AS QtyDelivered
                                    FROM         dbo.tblPDdetails
                                    WHERE     (PONo = @PONumber)
                                    GROUP BY id)as B On A.id = B.id   
Inner Join tblpodetailshistory as C on A.id =C.id

where A.PONo = @PONumber)
END
```

I got this Error.

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is       not introduced with EXISTS.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: The error message explains very specifically what the problem is and what the solution would be., in very clear wording  Did you read the actual words in the error message? What part isn't clear?

Comment: @KenWhite sorry i am a newbie and SQL i just want to innerjoin the Qtydelivered on  my first table...when i run the sub query it seems ok. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the column names and From keyword in the outer select statement

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[POBalance]  @PONumber nvarchar(50)
AS BEGIN
Select Description, POqty, PDQty, Balance, Unit, Unitprice, Partialflag  from ( 
Select 
    A.Description,
    C.qty as POqty,
    B.QtyDelivered as PDQty, 
    case when A.partialflag ='false' 
    then '0'
    else
    A.qty  end as Balance,
    A.Unit,
    A.Unitprice,
    A.Partialflag 
from tblPOdetails as A

Inner Join  ( SELECT  id, SUM(Qty) AS QtyDelivered
                                    FROM         dbo.tblPDdetails
                                    WHERE     (PONo = @PONumber)
                                    GROUP BY id)as B On A.id = B.id   
Inner Join tblpodetailshistory as C on A.id =C.id

where A.PONo = @PONumber)
END
```

Actually you don't need to write the outer select, it can be rewritten as

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[POBalance]  @PONumber nvarchar(50)
AS BEGIN

Select 
    A.Description,
    C.qty as POqty,
    B.QtyDelivered as PDQty, 
    case when A.partialflag ='false' 
    then '0'
    else
    A.qty  end as Balance,
    A.Unit,
    A.Unitprice,
    A.Partialflag 
from tblPOdetails as A

Inner Join  ( SELECT  id, SUM(Qty) AS QtyDelivered
                                    FROM         dbo.tblPDdetails
                                    WHERE     (PONo = @PONumber)
                                    GROUP BY id)as B On A.id = B.id   
Inner Join tblpodetailshistory as C on A.id =C.id

where A.PONo = @PONumber
END
```

Comment: it works...true no need for the outer select statement.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at the beginning of your query,

```
Select( Select ....
```

Remove the initial "Select (" and retry the query. When you run a

```
Select (Select ..)
```

the second select can only return one column (unless you concatenate the returned data).